# place icon in WordPress page title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This website is run with WordPress. The theme has a Facebook button which is displaying in the header.

I want to move the theme's Facebook button into the page title line. 
[Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNd9l.png).
I was thinking I could copy this code into the child theme someplace.

```
<a class="genericon_parent genericon genericon-facebook-alt"  title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/karen.b.russell.54" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.facebook.com/karen.b.russell.54'); return false;"><span class="screen-reader-text">Facebook</span> </a>
```

I have copied that code into content.php, content-none.php, content-single.php, content-page.php but now it is not displaying correctly. [This is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNrpL.png).

I am thinking that I can copy the CSS formatting from the themes button in the header to the new one in the content titles. When I tried to copy the css over it didn't work.

How do I tweak the button (circled in the second image) to look like the first?

The live code can be viewed at `healthylifeadvisors.com`

I see the original button seems to be using this css:

```
.site .widget_catchadaptive_social_icons a.genericon {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border: 1px solid #eee;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
color: #404040;
margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
padding: 5px;}
```

and

```
healthylifeadvisors.com/media="all"
.genericon {
font-size: 16px;
vertical-align: top;
text-align: center;
-moz-transition: color .1s ease-in 0;
-webkit-transition: color .1s ease-in 0;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Genericons";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
line-height: 1;
text-decoration: inherit;
text-transform: none;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
speak: none;}
```

The CSS being shown when I inspect the new button is:

```
.entry-title, .entry-title a {
color: #404040;
}
healthylifeadvisors.com/media="all"
.genericon {
font-size: 16px;
vertical-align: top;
text-align: center;
-moz-transition: color .1s ease-in 0;
-webkit-transition: color .1s ease-in 0;
display: inline-block;
font-family: "Genericons";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
line-height: 1;
text-decoration: inherit;
text-transform: none;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
speak: none;
}
a {
font-weight: 700;
color: #00BB58;
}
healthylifeadvisors.com/media="all"
a {
color: #21759b;
text-decoration: none;}
healthylifeadvisors.com/media="all"
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
border: 0;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-style: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
margin: 0;
outline: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sean, we'll need a bit more information. Have you tried to do this and it isn't working? Where did you put it in the screenshot you include?

Comment: The first screen shot is just the default theme placement of the button. I have updated my OP with a second screen shot plus mentioned the pages in which I have placed the HTML. The problem now is CSS.

Comment: It would be a lot faster if you provided a [mcve] of your request. As in code, not pictures. I can't inspect pictures. Or at least a link to the live webiste.

Comment: The live website in at the bottom of the OP. I can't link it because I don't have enough stackexchange reputation for 3 links. I'll update the OP with the CSS I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.entry-title a.genericon {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  color: #404040;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.entry-title a.genericon-facebook-alt:hover {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  border-color: #3b5998;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect. The "f" is just a touch off center compared to the original.

Comment: No, it's not. It's an optical illusion, because the original sits above a circle. But feel free to adjust padding if you think it's required. Updated with `color:white` on hover.

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much Andrei (: